# fancyBox 2 Vimeo embedding not working

Tags: fancybox-2, vimeo

I'm trying to embed a Vimeo video using [fancyBox 2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples). I'm able to make the lightbox pop up, but all I get is a spinning loading icon that lasts forever.

I did a bunch of searching on similar Vimeo questions here on StackExchange, but implementing things others suggested has not solved the issue.

I've now even created a fresh test site (plain HTML doc with linked files in local directory), and then used the code listed in the fancyBox documentation section on using Media Helpers ([Extended Functionality](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples)) line-for-line, but that's not working either. Same loading spinner, stuck forever.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is not working? Testing in both Safari 7 and Chrome. In Safari I get the stuck loading spinner. In Chrome I get an error page within the lightbox that says "The file or directory could not be found."

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>

<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox media helpers -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',
            helpers : {
                media : {}
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <a class="fancybox-media" href="https://vimeo.com/78112273">Video</a>

</body>
```

All I get with that is a stuck spinner and an error page.

Any help and suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Your code works just fine http://jsfiddle.net/8hMLb/ it should be something else but hard to say unless you share a link

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your page has a valid DOCTYPE and most importantly, note that the case seems to impact on whether the video actually gets loaded when the popup is displayed. (You need lowercase 'html' in the doctype declaration)

ie. Using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```

fixed it for me... This is probably why your example works in jsfiddle.